# Clear textarea value

Tags: javascript, html

I want to clear the textarea but that the cursor stays there and that I don't have to click on the textarea again to write the message. I use this `$ ('textarea').val('')` now but the cursor disappears and I have to click again to send the message I want to send the message like on the discord and you can still write without clicking on the textarea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('textarea').val('').focus()`

https://jsfiddle.net/ghfkarbs/